# Where did this mysterious 10 reputation come from?

Tags: support, reputation

A few minutes ago I got a random +10 reputation while I didn't do anything, nor anything got upvoted today.

This image should explain it all:

[image]

Here is the bottom of my https://stackoverflow.com/reputation:

```
-- 2011-11-05 rep +15   = 11064     
 2   8035311 (5)
 2   8035311 (5)
 1   8035335 (2)
 1   8021617 (2)
 1   7896061 (2)
 2   8035311 (5)
-- 2011-11-07 rep +21   = 11085     

** rep today: 0
** rep this week (2011-11-06 - 2011-11-12): 21
** rep this month (2011-11-01 - 2011-11-30): 220
** rep this quarter (2011-10-01 - 2011-12-31): 423
** rep this year (2011-01-01 - 2011-12-31): 10984
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 11085 :)

days represented 176
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 12 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 13 days
```

### Edit: after earning reputation the bug persists:

[image]

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/reputation, scroll all the way to the bottom and see if anything's recorded there for today.

Comment: @BoltClock: updated the question with that info.

Comment: Possibly a question you have answered in the past and which had been upvoted once was undeleted.

Comment: @Oded: how could I confirm that?

Comment: I've never found a way to confirm rep gain/loss from deletes/undeletes :(

Comment: Trigger a rep recacl and see if it's still there?

Comment: @ShawnChin: rep recalc fixed the difference.

Comment: Perhaps a downvote was removed?

Comment: Maybe someone upvoted one of your answers then regretted it and undone the vote.

Answer (score 7):

Since a rep recalc fixed it, it's likely that someone upvoted an answer of yours on a question that was deleted just after the upvote.

Comment: The weird part is that I was browsing SO, then I refreshed and I saw the counter jump from 150 to 160 without me undeleting/deleting something.

Comment: On a site with thousands of simultaneous users performing hundreds of operations per second, while this is rare, it can occur.  This sort of situation usually goes like this: Some user happens on an old question which should have been deleted, upvotes your answer, then performs and action that bumps the question (such as adding their own answer, or editing a post).  A mod notices the question and deletes it.  It's rare to see it happen, but it actually happens more than one might think.